# Update phpmyadmin config.inc.php file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

When you download and extract latest phpMyAdmin, it comes with a `config.sample.inc.php` file. I would like to set a random `blowfish_secret` value on this line:

> $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

So, what I have tried so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php;
search="\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';"; 
replace="\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '1234';"; 
sed -i -e 's/$search/$replace/g' config.inc.php; 
# debug
echo $search;
echo $replace;
cat config.inc.php;
```

When I tested this script, the copied `config.inc.php` file does not appear to have been updated. Any ideas why? the `search` & `replace` fields are correctly getting set:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to copy/paste and don't use images for the futur

Comment: Don't use semicolon on bash. Bash don't need semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
sed -i "s/\$cfg\[.blowfish_secret.\]\s*=.*/$replace/" file
```

If you put *single-quotes* around variables, the variables can't be expanded